# How to display different MySQL results to different users?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that holds a list of leads. I have agents that need to go through that list. What I want is divide the leads equally among `X` agents. For example, if the table contains 20,000 leads and I have 10 agents; this means 2000 leads per agent. If I have 100 agents, the system should understand that it represents 200 leads per agent etc,. How can I display the results to each agent so that they all work on a different part of the table?

```
Agent 1 | 0 to 2000    | page 1,2
Agent 2 | 2001 to 4000 | page 3,4
Agent 3 | ... etc.
```

This is the code I have right now. It works to create pagination.

```
 $page_count = 0;
// make your LIMIT query here as shown above
// determine page number from $_GET
if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if(false == $page) {
        $page = 1;
    }
}

// set the number of items to display per page
$items_per_page = 100;

if (0 === $row_count) {  
    // maybe show some error since there is nothing in your table
} else {
   // determine page_count
   $page_count = (int)ceil($row_count / $items_per_page);
   // double check that request page is in range
   if($page > $page_count) {
        // error to user, maybe set page to 1
        $page = 1;
   }
}
// build query
$offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;

 if(isset($_GET['outboundcampaign'])){
  //retrieve information from prospects
$get_blog_posts_query = $conn->prepare("select * from mk_prospects where current_website_host=? order by dateCreated desc LIMIT ?,?");
$get_blog_posts_query->bind_param("sii",$campaignid,$offset,$items_per_page);
$get_blog_posts_query->execute();
$selectprospectsqueryResult = $get_blog_posts_query->get_result();

  }
```

Comment: You already answered your own question: count(leads) / count(agents) = no. leads per agent... sql query with offset & limit.. shouldn't be too hard. You could do a one-time assignment, using an extra table..

Comment: @LarsStegelitz : Can you show with concrete coding example? The math is not hard. It's the displaying part that complicates things. The system needs to recognize it's a different agent looking at the table because otherwise we're back at case 1 and all the agents will be looking at same data. They are logged in the system with a session. So say I'm logged in as agent 1, I need to see the  first 2000 rows of the table. If I test and log in as agent 2, I should see the second 2000 rows etc. The pages should be different not all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clear if I understood it properly, you want your system to be able to understand how many records each agent should be able to see based on agents number, where they're supposed to see different records, for example:

Agent 1: 1-200

Agent 2: 201-400

Is it right?

If so, I believe you can follow the following line of thinking:

1. Query in a table how many registered agents you have.
2. Do a count query to check total leads registered in your database
3. Divide total leads / number of agents. This is **how many records each agent should be able to see**.

But before we continue the rest of the code, we gotta understand a few things, which is not clear for me in your question:

1. What's the idea for your "look into diff part of table"? First registered agent should see from 1-100, second registered from 101-200?
2. If an agent should not have access to your application anymore, agent record will be removed from your database or just a field set as "deleted"? I'm asking this, because this would change the order of the agents in your database, in case we use the logic in the **1.** question.

Can you clarify for us what kind of ordenation you plan to do for agents? After this, we can figure out a solution for you problem.

Comment: **What's the idea for your "look into diff part of table"? First registered agent should see from 1-100, second registered from 101-200?** You're basically repeating what I said in my question. That is exactly what I mean `:-)`

The agents are logged in the system with a session. So say I'm logged in as agent 1, I need to see the first 2000 rows of the table. If I test and log in as agent 2, I should see the second 2000 rows etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not repeating exactly what you said in your question. You say  that every agent should see part of your table, but you don't define how you're going to use the logic to define which agent is 1 or 2, see that I'm saying that FIRST REGISTERED agent should see the first records, not the FIRST AGENT (which could've a logic defined by scores or any other thing :-) ). But since you look to have this defined, multiply leads per agent by agent number and use it as offset.

Agent 1: leads per agent * 1
Agent 2: leads per agent * 2

Comment: **multiply leads per agent by agent number and use it as offset. Agent 1: leads per agent * 1 Agent 2: leads per agent * 2** something is missing in this math equation because when testing I need to add `$page` and `$items_per_ page` variable as well for it to generate pages properly for the agents.

Comment: Your limit condition will be the $items_per_page variable. Your offset should actually be something like this: (**leads per agent** * **AGENT_NUMBER**) + (**$items_per_page** * **$page**).